# индексировать сайт и обойти verify страница

Tags: php, оптимизация-сайтов, индексация, поисковые-системы

На сайте нужен verify 18+
но проблема такая google bot, yandex bot будут сканировать только этот страница (verify.php)
как могу дать им доступ на сайт без verify чтобы боты с могли индексировать сайт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашла ответ если кому-то понадобится

```
function isBot(&$botname = ''){
$bots = array(
'rambler','googlebot','aport','yahoo','msnbot','turtle','mail.ru','omsktele',
'yetibot','picsearch','sape.bot','sape_context','gigabot','snapbot','alexa.com',
'megadownload.net','askpeter.info','igde.ru','ask.com','qwartabot','yanga.co.uk',
'scoutjet','similarpages','oozbot','shrinktheweb.com','aboutusbot','followsite.com',
'dataparksearch','google-sitemaps','appEngine-google','feedfetcher-google',
'liveinternet.ru','xml-sitemaps.com','agama','metadatalabs.com','h1.hrn.ru',
'googlealert.com','seo-rus.com','yaDirectBot','yandeG','yandex',
'yandexSomething','Copyscape.com','AdsBot-Google','domaintools.com',
'Nigma.ru','bing.com','dotnetdotcom'
);
foreach($bots as $bot)
if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false){
  $botname = $bot;
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Использовать очень просто:

```
if( isBot($bname) ) echo 'На сайте сейчас '.$bname;
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Правилами поисковиков это запрещено.

2) Полный список IP-адресов ботов держится в секрете. По IP их не вычислишь.

Никак.